# Why uTorrent doesn't respect upload limit?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

I have set an upload limit of 30kB/s, but sometimes it is uploading 100kB/s. I have tested uTorrent and BitTorrent and they have the same problem.  I disabled the setting "use more upload slot if upload < 90%". I have set 30kB/s limit both in the current torrent preferences and in the general preferences.

Why does it still use more bandwidth?

EDIT. Found the solution, enable "limit local peer bandwidth, under bittorrent tab"

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're not just confusing kilobytes and kilobits?

Comment: On the other hand, 30kB/s = 180kb/s.

Comment: [30kB = 240 kilobits, actually](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=30kB+in+kilobit). @Olli

Comment: @oKtosiTe: well, simple multiplications are so hard. And yes, true.

Comment: …and with [Google’s Calculator](https://www.google.com/search?q=30+KBps+in+Kbps)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check if the upload is going to a peer on your local network.

utorrent, for some reason does not limit the upload rate to local peers, even if a global upload rate limit is set

Comment: Good point. Some providers even distribute [Class C addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network#Introduction_of_address_classes) to their client, so that might be something to check.

Comment: What do you mean by local network? My ISP acutually uses NAT so do you mean every other poeple with my same ISP? Other than that I don't have any LAN here

Comment: @yes123: I have seen ISP's that give out addresses in the 10.0.0.0 and 192.0.0.0 address ranges. If they do, uTorrent might confuse other users of the same provider with local clients. This is very hypothetical, though.

Comment: @oktosite: hm yes, my isp does give those ip to their clients (behind the nat) (I believe every ISP that uses NAT does it) So the dumb bittorrent thinks it's itnernal traffic and doens't limit it =/ doh =/

Comment: If your router gives you a Class C address, that's a whole different story. I'm talking about the situation where people outside of the network behind your router/modem/outlet would also be represented with 10.0.0.0 or 192.0.0.0 addresses. If they're not, then my comments can be ignored. You can check for this on the "Peers" tab in uTorrent. (Disable "Resolve IPs" by right-clicking there.) @yes123

Comment: @oktosite: i don't get what you mean. I am alone behind my router. I don't have any personal LAN. (tho my IPS brings internet at me with an ethernet cable and a NAT)

Comment: The fact alone that you _have_ a router in all likelihood means that what I said does _not_ apply to you. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: uTorrent _can_ limit local transfers. You just have to [tell it to in the preferences](http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?id=93018). The reason that it doesn't by default is because it makes little sense in 99% of cases. You typically configure your uTorrent network settings based on your internet bandwidth, but transfers to local peers don't use your internet bandwidth and are usually capable of many times the transfer rate. So why would you throttle your local transfers as if they were internet transfers and turn a 5 min. transfer into an 8 hour transfer?

Answer (score 7):

Be sure that Apply rate limit to uTP connections is checked in your settings

Comment: doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel suggested, you may confuse kilobytes and kilobits. At least in uTorrent speed is set using kilobytes per second (kB/s).

One kilobyte is 8 kilobits, so 30kB is ~240kb/s. It might be 100kb/s, if there isn't many people downloading it, or if your network connection limits it to slower speed.

Another possibilities are bug in both uTorrent and Bittorrent. Or protocol overhead is really high for some reason. Or finally, if your bandwidth monitor bugs for some reason.

Comment: I don't think uTorrent displays kbit/s anywhere.

Comment: There's no bug in uTorrent and BitTorrent's global upload rate setting. And the bittorrent protocol certainly doesn't have a 200%+ overhead. (Even if it did, the client would still be limiting the TCP transfer rate, which includes any bittorrent protocol overhead.)

Answer (score 1):

one thing I noticed that fixed upload exceeding limit issue was that the "Apply rate limit to transport overhead" and "Apply rate limit to UTP connections" boxes were unchecked. This must have happended when I went to the newest version, cus I noticed my download speed suffering the very next day. Once I checked those 2 boxes the upload speed went from 300k plus to the 150k I had set. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that the upload limit you set in uTorrent is respected, go to Options > Preferences > Bandwidth > Global Rate Limit Options and make sure that the "Apply rate limit to transport overhead" and "Apply rate limit to uTP connections" boxes are checked/enabled.

This is the answer and solution to your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a MAC user then do the following

Download **HardwareIOTools** (Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> More Developer Tools…). In that DMG find **Network Link Conditioner.prefPane** . Open and install it and create custom profile for Network Link Conditioner (duplicate your current network profile and modify it).

[image]

Comment: this is not working in Mac OS Sierra, any way to limit upload in Mac OS Sierra ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a related issue, but if you're in a situation where you want to limit upload or background bandwidth used one important consideration here is the number of simultaneous connections.  You might find you get down to just 30kB/s just fine, but still have issues with your actually throughput because that 30kB/s is divided among 500 or more active connections to different peers.  In this case, sometimes a router or modem just won't handle it very well, or it becomes a flag that your isp uses to start traffic shaping or throttling on your connection.

Answer (score 0):

My quess is that your 'conspiracy theory' of ISP or BOTH torrent client makers is not possible.
What info would they like from you what they could not test by them self. child porn maybe?
Just see your µtorrent page connection and put a mark to every four selection and let it choose port by random and my limiter is working as I have set it, no slowness nor errors on torrent or files, even the µtorrent 1.8.4 has been fastest up-loader and dl'r. Not the newest one either. 
- mmf -

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **Answer with Graphics**

1) Install the latest update from uTorrent website

2) Enable (Check) the option 'Apply rate limit to uTP Connections' and 'Apply rate limit to transport overhead' as shown in the following snapshot!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not a real solution but it could be a possible explanation and a good workaround for this over-discussed bug.
Go to "scheduler" and, if you're not using it, mark the entire time panel with the "light green" color (click several times on the time panel to get the right color and then drag the pointer to fill the entire panel).
Then set an upload limit.
I believe that some programs that create middle, hidden proxies to handle various net services (like Internet Download Manager, Net Limiter or some Wireless Printers drivers and software) may set to 127.0.0.1 the outgoing traffic to catch it and possibly intervene.
Then, right after, the UDP packets are re-enveloped with the right external IP address.
This may deceive uTorrent making it think that all the peers you're uploading to are on your LAN (notoriously not subjected to global bandwidth limitations). 
This is a vague theory anyway the suggested trick worked for me. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

The reason the upload limit may seems to be ignored is because it is not applied for local peers. Peers that may be on the same subnet as you.

But fortunately qbittorent has the option of limiting local peers also.

Just go to Tools --> Options ---> Speed ---> Apply rate limit to peers on LAN.

And that should do it.